# I need a 'female' 120V AC Plug / socket for a wall plate?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, wire

I cannot find what I am looking for anywhere, I don't even know what to search.

Something that would be the child of these two, if they had one.

[image]

I realize you can buy a kit that includes this piece, but I don't need the whole kit. I don't want to spend $50 on it when I only need may be $1.50 in parts.

I need to run power up to a socket at the top of the wall.

What is the name of what I am looking for, does one exist already? Thank you!

Comment: an extension cord?

Comment: https://www.cableleader.com/6ft-18-awg-universal-power-cord-iec320-c13-to-nema-5-15p.html.

Comment: the male plug is C14 and the female plug is C13 .... you probably need a regular computer power cord with a 110 V NEMA connector at one end and a C13 connector at the other end

Comment: Are you trying to hook up a TV and conceal the cords? Because literally everyone wants that. And there are many many solutions on the market. Some of them are even code legal!

Comment: @Harper oh sure of course they do. But for 60 bucks I get a sub standard solution which doesn’t do all I want. I have completed the task at the cost of 50 for everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want there is an inlet and I recommend you stay within Nema 5-15. It is perfectly legitimate to connect a Nema outlet to a Nema inlet with inside-the-wall wiring. Since there is an inlet involved, do not under any circumstance connect this section of cabling to Mains power in any other way.

You want to do your inside-the-wall wiring with perfectly standard and common Nema 5 - 15 outlets and inlets.

Now, if you need to connect to IEC c-13 / c14 ends on your equipment, you can get the adapter cables necessary to go from IEC to Nema without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "Male power inlet". Male here refers to the pins/prongs, rather than the way the plug inserts.

However, it's likely there's a better and safer way to do what you're planning. If you do decide to proceed despite warnings, at least label this installation so the next inspector/owner can figure out what happened.

Comment: i will find a safer alternative. There were kits on Amazon that did this very thing, which is why I was curious how to do it myself

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Datacomm-50-3323-WH-KIT-Panel-Organizer-Solution/dp/B001PB7UVA this kit does exactly what i said - and has 1400 reviews

Comment: Ah, I see. That's not a "standard" way to hide TV power in the wall, but it's not a totally unreasonable way. Most people will put a normal power receptacle behind the TV and connect that directly to the house wiring. HDMI/network/audio cables run vertically through the wall with some kind of plate at either end (https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=12572)

Comment: Having an inlet internally connected to an outlet is perfectly legit.